# Facebook like button not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to get my facebook like button to load.

The pages meta tags pass the facebook debugger tests, but the button itself does not load

http://ping-it.theonconnection.com/properties/31

Comment: Can you send over the source code of the button you embedded verbatim?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

...twice in your document, which is probably throwing off your script.  This should only appear once.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your HTML code being served down from http://ping-it.theonconnection.com/properties/31 and I could not find where you're putting in your like button code.

I do not see any like button code in there.  However I do see the FB.init, the all.js file, and TWO fb-roots.